# How would I write idiomatic kotlin code that loops over a subprocess and processes output from it?

Tags: kotlin, exec

I want to write some kotlin code that essentially runs a command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mycommand.sh")
```

But, in this case `mycommand.sh` will never exit. It will sporadically output text that I want to process. Imagine the output is like this:

```
FOOBAR 1234
BARFOO 54657
ETCETC 9876
```

Say the first line comes in at 5 seconds, then the second at 10 seconds, and the third at 15 seconds.

How would I write code that receives each line as it comes in, and processes it?
 For example, maybe I want to extract the words in all caps and pull out the number that follows and then stores those two pieces of text as key-values in a hash map.

As a bonus, I would love to know how to terminate the subprocess (signal with SIGINT?) from within the kotlin program.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
 val inStream = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(proc.inputStream))
 val map = inStream.lines()
               //maybe you need a more sufficient solution here
               .map { it.split(" ") } 
               .map { it[0] to it[1] }.toList()
```

This will result in a `List` of `Pair`s then. The `infix` method `to` creates the `Pair`s, which are simple key value associations.